# Cubist Model Tree Overlapping Rules

Tags: r, regression, machine-learning, cart, data-mining

Can someone help me understand the output of a cubist model created by the R Cubist package? The documentation package manual for objects of class "cubist" seems to be nonexistent. Looking for information on the rule quest has me looking through c source code and without much success.

**Do these objects have any data in them that will allow me to visualize the tree and figure out the rules associated with the terminal nodes?**

Below is the output from a model. All predictors are factor variables. `model` is a cubist model. There are 98 instances in the data where some of the rules overlap. This is apparent in the output from the number of cases in each rule (total is 91277) and the number of training instances (91179). Based on the limited documentation I've been able to find I thought there might be some hierarchy at play and that a rule may be below a split and hence making the sum of all rule cases greater than the number of training instances. That is not the case though. As an example for this particular model there are 590 cases for rule 6, 177 cases for rule 12 and 78 cases where both of these rules are active at the same time. Interestingly rule 6 is not listed in the "splits" output below. I'm guessing this is telling me something but I'm not quit sure what.

**For these cases where more than one rule is active, what is the terminal node model?**

`cat(model$output) # print the output to the console`

```
---------------------------------

    Target attribute `outcome'

Read 91179 cases (690 attributes) from undefined.data

Model:

  Rule 1: [18998 cases, mean 0.0166252, range 0.011635 to 0.02136263, est err 0.0001783]

    if
    X592 = 0
    X689 = 0
    X903 = 2
    then
    outcome = 0.0165942

  Rule 2: [1467 cases, mean 0.0171435, range 0.01602197 to 0.02155337, est err 0.0004971]

    if
    X592 = 1
    X698 = 0
    X888 = 2
    X903 = 2
    then
    outcome = 0.0167849

  Rule 3: [168 cases, mean 0.0181110, range 0.011635 to 0.01888304, est err 0.0004205]

    if
    X423 = 0
    X689 = 0
    X903 = 0
    then
    outcome = 0.0183108

  Rule 4: [430 cases, mean 0.0188719, range 0.01621271 to 0.0202182, est err 0.0009363]

    if
    X592 = 1
    X888 = 4
    X903 = 2
    then
    outcome = 0.0194553

  Rule 5: [9753 cases, mean 0.0195881, range 0.01812009 to 0.02117189, est err 0.0002318]

    if
    X346 = 0
    X423 = 1
    X441 = 0
    X903 = 0
    then
    outcome = 0.019646

  Rule 6: [590 cases, mean 0.0212197, range 0.01678493 to 0.02479591, est err 0.0010095]

    if
    X689 = 0
    X698 = 1
    then
    outcome = 0.0209812

  Rule 7: [648 cases, mean 0.0222725, range 0.02098116 to 0.02346075, est err 0.0002749]

    if
    X689 = 1
    X900 in {0, 3}
    then
    outcome = 0.0223163

  Rule 8: [12832 cases, mean 0.0235755, range 0.02174411 to 0.02594034, est err 0.0002139]

    if
    X689 = 1
    X900 = 1
    X915 in {0, 2}
    then
    outcome = 0.0236515

  Rule 9: [10416 cases, mean 0.0240797, range 0.02174411 to 0.02613107, est err 0.0002605]

    if
    X484 = 2
    X689 = 1
    X915 = 1
    X1062 in {0, 1, 4, 7, 8}
    then
    outcome = 0.024033

  Rule 10: [4317 cases, mean 0.0243195, range 0.02288853 to 0.02594034, est err 0.0003266]

    if
    X483 = 2
    X484 = 2
    X915 = 1
    X1062 = 2
    then
    outcome = 0.0244144

  Rule 11: [1817 cases, mean 0.0243281, range 0.02307927 to 0.02594034, est err 0.0005629]

    if
    X711 = 0
    X1062 = 2
    then
    outcome = 0.024033

  Rule 12: [177 cases, mean 0.0246289, range 0.011635 to 0.02689403, est err 0.0017732]

    if
    X441 in {-1447, 5}
    X689 = 0
    X903 = 0
    then
    outcome = 0.0263218

  Rule 13: [13683 cases, mean 0.0251357, range 0.02327001 to 0.02632181, est err 0.0002123]

    if
    X483 = 0
    X711 = 1
    X915 = 1
    X1062 = 2
    then
    outcome = 0.0251774

  Rule 14: [15952 cases, mean 0.0252648, range 0.0242237 to 0.02632181, est err 0.0002027]

    if
    X484 = 1
    X915 = 1
    then
    outcome = 0.0251774

  Rule 15: [29 cases, mean 2.0473793, range 0.02002747 to 3.312352, est err 0.5484862]

    if
    X346 = 1
    then
    outcome = 1.9651713


Evaluation on training data (91179 cases, sampled):

    Average  |error|          0.0005271
    Relative |error|               0.14
    Correlation coefficient        0.96


    Attribute usage:
      Conds  Model

       63%           X915
       48%           X689
       34%           X903
       34%           X484
       33%           X1062
       23%           X592
       20%           X483
       17%           X711
       15%           X900
       11%           X441
       11%           X423
       11%           X346
        2%           X698
        2%           X888


Time: 35.2 secs
```

`model$splits # print split information to the console`

```
    committee rule variable dir value  category  type percentile
703         1    2   "X888"        NA         2 type3         NA
713         1    4   "X888"        NA         4 type3         NA
717         1    5   "X441"        NA         0 type3         NA
727         1    7   "X900"        NA       0,3 type3         NA
731         1    8   "X915"        NA       0,2 type3         NA
733         1    8   "X900"        NA         1 type3         NA
736         1    9  "X1062"        NA 0,1,4,7,8 type3         NA
737         1    9   "X484"        NA         2 type3         NA
738         1    9   "X915"        NA         1 type3         NA
742         1   10   "X483"        NA         2 type3         NA
743         1   10  "X1062"        NA         2 type3         NA
744         1   10   "X915"        NA         1 type3         NA
745         1   10   "X484"        NA         2 type3         NA
748         1   11  "X1062"        NA         2 type3         NA
753         1   12   "X441"        NA   -1447,5 type3         NA
757         1   13   "X483"        NA         0 type3         NA
759         1   13  "X1062"        NA         2 type3         NA
760         1   13   "X915"        NA         1 type3         NA
763         1   14   "X484"        NA         1 type3         NA
764         1   14   "X915"        NA         1 type3         NA
```

In case anyone is interested in the input signal...
`plot(y$X1)`
[image: input signal]

`plot(y$X1, ylim=c(0.01, 0.03)`
[image: input signal, small values]